# Blend4Web does not render in Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: blend4web

All my Blend4Web.html files (which worked fine on my Mac) don't work anymore. I double click the html and I see the Blend4Web Wheel for a couple of seconds (as usual), then the buttons appear, but the 3D Object does not load. I never updated the drivers for the gpu and it always worked. Apart from the Mac OS update, the only other thing I changed was to always use the the graphic card and not switch between the internal and external. Any ideas why this does not work anymore would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Chrome 60 bug which is already fixed by Google in Chrome 61. Nevertheless, we're going to include a workaround in the upcoming 17.06 LTS and 17.08 releases.